# How to copy entire row from one source sheet to destination Sheet and delete row from source based on Date Criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I am using an excel worksheet which consisted of two sheets. The First Source Sheet name is "Submitted" which looks like as under. [image: Source Sheet]

1. I want to search all the rows which are less than today() date from the column (F) circle red.
2. If rows are found, I want to transfer them to the destination sheet on the next blank row. In another case, if data are not found the sub should be closed without doing anything.
3. Once the data is transfer the particulars row/rows should be deleted from the source sheet.

The Destination sheet looks like this.
[image]

I am using the following code but it is not working as I want.

```
    Sub MM1()
Dim Check As Range, r As Long, lastrow2 As Long, lastrow As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
lastrow = Worksheets("Submitted").UsedRange.Rows.Count
lastrow2 = Worksheets("Agreements").UsedRange.Rows.Count
If lastrow2 = 1 Then lastrow2 = 0
    For r = lastrow To 2 Step -1
        If Range("F12" & r).Value <= Now() Then
            Rows(r).Cut Destination:=Worksheets("Agreements").Range("A" & lastrow2 + 1)
            lastrow2 = lastrow2 + 1
            Else:
        End If
    Next r
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Please suggest me the best way and where I am doing wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You shoud try to define your ranges/rows correctly, because otherwise it won't know, where it needs to pick the data up from, e.g. `Rows(r).Cut` should be `Worksheets("Submitted").Rows(r).Cut`. Also define your worksheets in the beginning to keep your code lean and give the variables names that anyone can follow.

```
Sub MMM1()
Dim loop1 As Long, lastrow2 As Long, lastrow As Long
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim wsSub As Worksheet, wsAgr As Worksheet

Set wsSub = wb.Worksheets("Submitted")
Set wsAgr = wb.Worksheets("Agreements")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
lastrow = wsSub.Cells(wsSub.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lastrow2 = wsAgr.Cells(wsAgr.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

If lastrow2 = 1 Then lastrow2 = 0
    For loop1 = 12 To lastrow Step 1
        If wsSub.Range("F" & loop1).Value <= Date Then
            wsSub.Rows(loop1).Cut Destination:=wsAgr.Range("A" & lastrow2 + 1)
            lastrow2 = lastrow2 + 1
        End If
    Next loop1

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: this is not working as I describe. It also not transferring data and not deleting rows.

Comment: What exactly is not working? What error are you getting?